# Why do multiple DOM node types map to the same numeric value?

Tags: javascript, dom

While reading about DOM node object types from the book DOM Enlightenment (http://domenlightenment.com/#1.2), I found it weird that multiple object types map to the same numeric value. For example, `ELEMENT_NODE` and `DOCUMENT_POSITION_DISCONNECTED` map to `1`, `ATTRIBUTE_NODE` and `DOCUMENT_POSITION_PRECEDING` map to `2`, and so on. You can run

```
for(var key in Node){
    console.log(key,' = ' + Node[key]); 
};
```

to see the list of all the supported node object types and their numeric value.

Could someone please help me understand why multiple node object types map to the same numeric value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The former values, `ELEMENT_NODE` and `ATTRIBUTE_NODE` are to indicate node type ([mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType#Constants)). The latter, `DOCUMENT_POSITION_DISCONNECTED` and `DOCUMENT_POSITION_PRECEDING` are to indicate position via `Node​.compare​Document​Position()` ([mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/compareDocumentPosition)).

In essence, having them map to the same value is acceptable as they represent different enums / meanings.

As another example, if you were designing a zoo system, it would be ok to have an enum `tiger: 1, monkey: 2, elephant: 3, penguin: 4` and another (bit-)enum `{status_hungry: 0, status_thirsty: 2, status_happy: 4}` that overlapp in values because no single field will be expected to represent both.

Comment: Since they have different meanings, why not separate them into different objects? Having them in the same object (Node) could cause confusion.

Comment: That's (class prototype) where you usually store enums in a language that doesn't support a standard enums